# Телеграм бот на PHP. Опрос

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Начал написания собственного бота. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при вводе команды "/feedback" начинается опрос (фио, возраст и тд), т.е. при просбе вести фио, бот должен ожидать ответа, но я не могу понять как это сделать. Может кто нибудь знает. Связь с помощью WebHook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Храните текущее состояние пользователя. Проще всего это делать с помощью `$_SESSION`. Делаете по умолчанию `$_SESSION['bot']['state'] = 'normal'` и при каждом сообщении просто проверяете - если normal - то обрабатываете как обычно, иначе используете `switch ($_SESSION['bot']['state'])` и обрабатываете уже как нужно. Т.е. после того как получаете команду /feedback меняете `$_SESSION['bot']['state'] = 'feedback'` И затем заполняете данные `$_SESSION['bot']['feedback']['first'] = 'My first opinion'` можете тут же проверять валидность введенного и если не по форме - говорить "Не правильно, нужно в формате...".

Более муторный, но корректный вариант - хранить это все еще и в базе данных, тогда у вас будет база ответов всех пользователей. Да и можно сделать их аутентификацию по логину-паролю и вообще все что душе угодно